# set default value of datepreference

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using this datepreference picker:

https://mikeburnscoder.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/datepreference-an-android-library/

I start the picker in my preferences screeen via this code:

```
<com.Test.preference.DatePreference
            android:key="start_date"
            android:title="Start at"
            android:defaultValue="" />
```

This is working well. But I cannot find out how to set a default date. 
Now it start with 1. Jan 1970. But I want it to set to current date.

I tried it via

```
android:defaultValue="12.09.2011"
```

But this lets the app crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never set defaults of dates in xml. I assume that it is looking for a long value that represents the # of millis since 01/01/1970. So you're going to need some long string of numbers.

here is an example : `1315868978`

As for how you can default it to the current date and time. I don't think you can do this from xml. But in your java you could use System.currentTimeInMillis(). That would like something like this `prefs.getLong("time", System.currentTimeInMillis());`

Edit: I missed the fact that you were using a library. When I follow your link it looks you you formated the default wrong"

```
<org.bostonandroid.datepreference.DatePreference
  android:key="dob" android:title="@string/dob"
  android:defaultValue="1991.01.01" />
```

You need to do year first, not last.

Comment: I have tried it with  android:defaultValue="1315868978". But this shows also the 1970 date.

Comment: when you say it "shows" this to you, in what way is it being shown?

Comment: a dialog is popping up which. You can see it on the website I have posted above.

Comment: Thats working, thx! And to set it via code, I have to format the current date to that form, right?

Comment: yeah probably. I am not familiar with that object, it may have a method that lets you pass in the time as a long though. In that case you could just pass the currentTimeInMillis to that method.